# Black screen after apt upgrade when using GPU - Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: apt, 20.04, amd-graphics

Ubuntu Version: Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS 
CPU: Intel® Core™ i5-4590 CPU @ 3.30GHz × 4.
Integrated Graphics: Mesa Intel® HD Graphics 4600 (HSW GT2)
GPU: Radeon HD 8570

I recently did apt upgrade and since then, I am not getting output from my GPU. However, when I connect using the other display ports (using Intel Integrated Graphics), everything works fine.
If I change the output while the PC in turned on, it takes 5-10 seconds to open any window.
If I restart the PC while connected to GPU, Ubuntu logo show up and then monitor goes to sleep since there is no output.

I never installed any additional drivers for my GPU to work.

I ran BIOS test (while connected to GPU) and the GPU seems to be working.

Running this command gives the following output:

> sudo lshw -C display

```
*-display                 
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: Oland [Radeon HD 8570 / R5 430 OEM / R7 240/340 / Radeon 520 OEM]
   vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
   version: 00
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=radeon latency=0
   resources: irq:32 memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f7c00000-f7c3ffff ioport:e000(size=256) memory:f7c40000-f7c5ffff 
*-display
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 2
   bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
   version: 06
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list
   configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
   resources: irq:31 memory:f7800000-f7bfffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff ioport:f000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

I assume a newer version of some driver is causing this problem.

Is there a way to fix this or should I just keep upgrading apt until its fixed?

Update:
I found the error logs and I am adding them here. This might be helpful for fixing the problem.

> dmesg | egrep 'drm|radeon'

```
[    1.466230] systemd[1]: Starting Load Kernel Module drm...
[    1.483365] systemd[1]: modprobe@drm.service: Succeeded.
[    1.483639] systemd[1]: Finished Load Kernel Module drm.
[    1.975758] [drm] radeon kernel modesetting enabled.
[    1.975789] fb0: switching to radeondrmfb from VESA VGA
[    1.976443] radeon 0000:01:00.0: vgaarb: deactivate vga console
[    1.976658] [drm] initializing kernel modesetting (OLAND 0x1002:0x6611 0x1028:0x210B 0x00).
[    1.976690] radeon 0000:01:00.0: Invalid PCI ROM data signature: expecting 0x52494350, got 0xe808aa55
[    1.976811] radeon 0000:01:00.0: VRAM: 1024M 0x0000000000000000 - 0x000000003FFFFFFF (1024M used)
[    1.976813] radeon 0000:01:00.0: GTT: 2048M 0x0000000040000000 - 0x00000000BFFFFFFF
[    1.976818] [drm] Detected VRAM RAM=1024M, BAR=256M
[    1.976818] [drm] RAM width 64bits DDR
[    1.976832] [drm] radeon: 1024M of VRAM memory ready
[    1.976833] [drm] radeon: 2048M of GTT memory ready.
[    1.976839] [drm] Loading oland Microcode
[    1.992910] [drm] Internal thermal controller with fan control
[    1.999878] [drm] radeon: dpm initialized
[    2.001530] [drm] GART: num cpu pages 524288, num gpu pages 524288
[    2.003307] [drm] PCIE gen 3 link speeds already enabled
[    2.038757] [drm] PCIE GART of 2048M enabled (table at 0x0000000000165000).
[    2.038890] radeon 0000:01:00.0: WB enabled
[    2.038892] radeon 0000:01:00.0: fence driver on ring 0 use gpu addr 0x0000000040000c00
[    2.038894] radeon 0000:01:00.0: fence driver on ring 1 use gpu addr 0x0000000040000c04
[    2.038895] radeon 0000:01:00.0: fence driver on ring 2 use gpu addr 0x0000000040000c08
[    2.038896] radeon 0000:01:00.0: fence driver on ring 3 use gpu addr 0x0000000040000c0c
[    2.038897] radeon 0000:01:00.0: fence driver on ring 4 use gpu addr 0x0000000040000c10
[    2.039162] radeon 0000:01:00.0: fence driver on ring 5 use gpu addr 0x0000000000075a18
[    2.040388] radeon 0000:01:00.0: radeon: MSI limited to 32-bit
[    2.040465] radeon 0000:01:00.0: radeon: using MSI.
[    2.040485] [drm] radeon: irq initialized.
[    2.218138] [drm] ring test on 0 succeeded in 1 usecs
[    2.218145] [drm] ring test on 1 succeeded in 1 usecs
[    2.218149] [drm] ring test on 2 succeeded in 1 usecs
[    2.218155] [drm] ring test on 3 succeeded in 3 usecs
[    2.218160] [drm] ring test on 4 succeeded in 3 usecs
[    2.394198] [drm] ring test on 5 succeeded in 2 usecs
[    2.394205] [drm] UVD initialized successfully.
[    2.394322] [drm] ib test on ring 0 succeeded in 0 usecs
[    2.394693] [drm] ib test on ring 1 succeeded in 0 usecs
[    2.394722] [drm] ib test on ring 2 succeeded in 0 usecs
[    2.394750] [drm] ib test on ring 3 succeeded in 0 usecs
[    2.394776] [drm] ib test on ring 4 succeeded in 0 usecs
[    3.066505] [drm] ib test on ring 5 succeeded
[    3.067864] [drm] Radeon Display Connectors
[    3.067870] [drm] Connector 0:
[    3.067872] [drm]   DP-1
[    3.067873] [drm]   HPD1
[    3.067875] [drm]   DDC: 0x6540 0x6540 0x6544 0x6544 0x6548 0x6548 0x654c 0x654c
[    3.067880] [drm]   Encoders:
[    3.067881] [drm]     DFP1: INTERNAL_UNIPHY
[    3.067885] [drm] Connector 1:
[    3.067887] [drm]   DVI-I-1
[    3.067888] [drm]   HPD2
[    3.067890] [drm]   DDC: 0x6530 0x6530 0x6534 0x6534 0x6538 0x6538 0x653c 0x653c
[    3.067894] [drm]   Encoders:
[    3.067895] [drm]     DFP2: INTERNAL_UNIPHY
[    3.067897] [drm]     CRT1: INTERNAL_KLDSCP_DAC1
[    3.134139] [drm] fb mappable at 0xE0571000
[    3.134145] [drm] vram apper at 0xE0000000
[    3.134146] [drm] size 14745600
[    3.134148] [drm] fb depth is 24
[    3.134150] [drm]    pitch is 10240
[    3.134297] fbcon: radeondrmfb (fb0) is primary device
[    3.134465] radeon 0000:01:00.0: [drm] fb0: radeondrmfb frame buffer device
[    3.166458] [drm] Initialized radeon 2.50.0 20080528 for 0000:01:00.0 on minor 0
[    3.262273] [drm] amdgpu kernel modesetting enabled.
[   18.394588] radeon 0000:01:00.0: ring 0 stalled for more than 10236msec
[   18.394604] radeon 0000:01:00.0: GPU lockup (current fence id 0x0000000000000001 last fence id 0x0000000000000002 on ring 0)
[   18.906543] radeon 0000:01:00.0: ring 0 stalled for more than 10748msec
[   18.906560] radeon 0000:01:00.0: GPU lockup (current fence id 0x0000000000000001 last fence id 0x0000000000000002 on ring 0)
[   19.418519] radeon 0000:01:00.0: ring 0 stalled for more than 11260msec
[   19.418537] radeon 0000:01:00.0: GPU lockup (current fence id 0x0000000000000001 last fence id 0x0000000000000002 on ring 0)
[   19.930567] radeon 0000:01:00.0: ring 0 stalled for more than 11772msec
[   19.930582] radeon 0000:01:00.0: GPU lockup (current fence id 0x0000000000000001 last fence id 0x0000000000000002 on ring 0)
[   20.442539] radeon 0000:01:00.0: ring 0 stalled for more than 12284msec
[   20.442556] radeon 0000:01:00.0: GPU lockup (current fence id 0x0000000000000001 last fence id 0x0000000000000002 on ring 0)
[   20.954557] radeon 0000:01:00.0: ring 0 stalled for more than 12796msec
[   20.954575] radeon 0000:01:00.0: GPU lockup (current fence id 0x0000000000000001 last fence id 0x0000000000000002 on ring 0)
[   21.466530] radeon 0000:01:00.0: ring 0 stalled for more than 13308msec
[   21.466548] radeon 0000:01:00.0: GPU lockup (current fence id 0x0000000000000001 last fence id 0x0000000000000002 on ring 0)
[   21.978559] radeon 0000:01:00.0: ring 0 stalled for more than 13820msec
[   21.978575] radeon 0000:01:00.0: GPU lockup (current fence id 0x0000000000000001 last fence id 0x0000000000000002 on ring 0)
[   22.490532] radeon 0000:01:00.0: ring 0 stalled for more than 14332msec
[   22.490550] radeon 0000:01:00.0: GPU lockup (current fence id 0x0000000000000001 last fence id 0x0000000000000002 on ring 0)
[   23.002557] radeon 0000:01:00.0: ring 0 stalled for more than 14844msec
[   23.002574] radeon 0000:01:00.0: GPU lockup (current fence id 0x0000000000000001 last fence id 0x0000000000000002 on ring 0)
[   23.514553] radeon 0000:01:00.0: ring 0 stalled for more than 15356msec
[   23.514572] radeon 0000:01:00.0: GPU lockup (current fence id 0x0000000000000001 last fence id 0x0000000000000002 on ring 0)
[   24.026523] radeon 0000:01:00.0: ring 0 stalled for more than 15868msec
[   24.026534] radeon 0000:01:00.0: GPU lockup (current fence id 0x0000000000000001 last fence id 0x0000000000000002 on ring 0)
[   24.538530] radeon 0000:01:00.0: ring 0 stalled for more than 16380msec
[   24.538546] radeon 0000:01:00.0: GPU lockup (current fence id 0x0000000000000001 last fence id 0x0000000000000002 on ring 0)
[   25.050523] radeon 0000:01:00.0: ring 0 stalled for more than 16892msec
[   25.050539] radeon 0000:01:00.0: GPU lockup (current fence id 0x0000000000000001 last fence id 0x0000000000000002 on ring 0)
[   25.562529] radeon 0000:01:00.0: ring 0 stalled for more than 17404msec
[   25.562547] radeon 0000:01:00.0: GPU lockup (current fence id 0x0000000000000001 last fence id 0x0000000000000002 on ring 0)
[   26.074533] radeon 0000:01:00.0: ring 0 stalled for more than 17916msec
[   26.074549] radeon 0000:01:00.0: GPU lockup (current fence id 0x0000000000000001 last fence id 0x0000000000000002 on ring 0)
[   26.586488] radeon 0000:01:00.0: ring 0 stalled for more than 18428msec
[   26.586505] radeon 0000:01:00.0: GPU lockup (current fence id 0x0000000000000001 last fence id 0x0000000000000002 on ring 0)
[   27.098589] radeon 0000:01:00.0: ring 0 stalled for more than 18940msec
[   27.098605] radeon 0000:01:00.0: GPU lockup (current fence id 0x0000000000000001 last fence id 0x0000000000000002 on ring 0)
[   27.610531] radeon 0000:01:00.0: ring 0 stalled for more than 19452msec
[   27.610549] radeon 0000:01:00.0: GPU lockup (current fence id 0x0000000000000001 last fence id 0x0000000000000002 on ring 0)
[   28.122535] radeon 0000:01:00.0: ring 0 stalled for more than 19964msec
[   28.122551] radeon 0000:01:00.0: GPU lockup (current fence id 0x0000000000000001 last fence id 0x0000000000000002 on ring 0)
[   28.634537] radeon 0000:01:00.0: ring 0 stalled for more than 20476msec
[   28.634553] radeon 0000:01:00.0: GPU lockup (current fence id 0x0000000000000001 last fence id 0x0000000000000002 on ring 0)
[   29.146523] radeon 0000:01:00.0: ring 0 stalled for more than 20988msec
[   29.146541] radeon 0000:01:00.0: GPU lockup (current fence id 0x0000000000000001 last fence id 0x0000000000000002 on ring 0)
[   29.658526] radeon 0000:01:00.0: ring 0 stalled for more than 21500msec
[   29.658544] radeon 0000:01:00.0: GPU lockup (current fence id 0x0000000000000001 last fence id 0x0000000000000002 on ring 0)
[   30.170540] radeon 0000:01:00.0: ring 0 stalled for more than 22012msec
[   30.170556] radeon 0000:01:00.0: GPU lockup (current fence id 0x0000000000000001 last fence id 0x0000000000000002 on ring 0)
[   30.682533] radeon 0000:01:00.0: ring 0 stalled for more than 22524msec
[   30.682550] radeon 0000:01:00.0: GPU lockup (current fence id 0x0000000000000001 last fence id 0x0000000000000002 on ring 0)
[   31.194527] radeon 0000:01:00.0: ring 0 stalled for more than 23036msec
[   31.194545] radeon 0000:01:00.0: GPU lockup (current fence id 0x0000000000000001 last fence id 0x0000000000000002 on ring 0)
[   31.706532] radeon 0000:01:00.0: ring 0 stalled for more than 23548msec
[   31.706551] radeon 0000:01:00.0: GPU lockup (current fence id 0x0000000000000001 last fence id 0x0000000000000002 on ring 0)
[   32.218536] radeon 0000:01:00.0: ring 0 stalled for more than 24060msec
[   32.218555] radeon 0000:01:00.0: GPU lockup (current fence id 0x0000000000000001 last fence id 0x0000000000000002 on ring 0)
[   32.730507] radeon 0000:01:00.0: ring 0 stalled for more than 24572msec
[   32.730518] radeon 0000:01:00.0: GPU lockup (current fence id 0x0000000000000001 last fence id 0x0000000000000002 on ring 0)
[   33.242524] radeon 0000:01:00.0: ring 0 stalled for more than 25084msec
[   33.242541] radeon 0000:01:00.0: GPU lockup (current fence id 0x0000000000000001 last fence id 0x0000000000000002 on ring 0)
[   33.754529] radeon 0000:01:00.0: ring 0 stalled for more than 25596msec
[   33.754547] radeon 0000:01:00.0: GPU lockup (current fence id 0x0000000000000001 last fence id 0x0000000000000002 on ring 0)
[   34.266539] radeon 0000:01:00.0: ring 0 stalled for more than 26108msec
[   34.266555] radeon 0000:01:00.0: GPU lockup (current fence id 0x0000000000000001 last fence id 0x0000000000000002 on ring 0)
[   34.778563] radeon 0000:01:00.0: ring 0 stalled for more than 26620msec
[   34.778580] radeon 0000:01:00.0: GPU lockup (current fence id 0x0000000000000001 last fence id 0x0000000000000002 on ring 0)
[   35.290532] radeon 0000:01:00.0: ring 0 stalled for more than 27132msec
[   35.290548] radeon 0000:01:00.0: GPU lockup (current fence id 0x0000000000000001 last fence id 0x0000000000000002 on ring 0)
[   35.802495] radeon 0000:01:00.0: ring 0 stalled for more than 27644msec
[   35.802514] radeon 0000:01:00.0: GPU lockup (current fence id 0x0000000000000001 last fence id 0x0000000000000002 on ring 0)
[   36.314507] radeon 0000:01:00.0: ring 0 stalled for more than 28156msec
[   36.314520] radeon 0000:01:00.0: GPU lockup (current fence id 0x0000000000000001 last fence id 0x0000000000000002 on ring 0)
[   36.826534] radeon 0000:01:00.0: ring 0 stalled for more than 28668msec
[   36.826552] radeon 0000:01:00.0: GPU lockup (current fence id 0x0000000000000001 last fence id 0x0000000000000002 on ring 0)
[   37.348668] radeon 0000:01:00.0: ring 0 stalled for more than 29180msec
[   37.348684] radeon 0000:01:00.0: GPU lockup (current fence id 0x0000000000000001 last fence id 0x0000000000000002 on ring 0)
[   37.874821] radeon 0000:01:00.0: ring 0 stalled for more than 29692msec
[   37.874834] radeon 0000:01:00.0: GPU lockup (current fence id 0x0000000000000001 last fence id 0x0000000000000002 on ring 0)
[   38.399572] radeon 0000:01:00.0: ring 0 stalled for more than 30204msec
[   38.399590] radeon 0000:01:00.0: GPU lockup (current fence id 0x0000000000000001 last fence id 0x0000000000000002 on ring 0)
[   38.923887] radeon 0000:01:00.0: ring 0 stalled for more than 30716msec
[   38.923893] radeon 0000:01:00.0: GPU lockup (current fence id 0x0000000000000001 last fence id 0x0000000000000002 on ring 0)
[   39.446998] radeon 0000:01:00.0: ring 0 stalled for more than 31228msec
[   39.447016] radeon 0000:01:00.0: GPU lockup (current fence id 0x0000000000000001 last fence id 0x0000000000000002 on ring 0)
[   39.969769] radeon 0000:01:00.0: ring 0 stalled for more than 31740msec
[   39.969786] radeon 0000:01:00.0: GPU lockup (current fence id 0x0000000000000001 last fence id 0x0000000000000002 on ring 0)
[   40.634473] radeon 0000:01:00.0: Saved 20 dwords of commands on ring 0.
[   40.634544] radeon 0000:01:00.0: GPU softreset: 0x00000049
[   40.634546] radeon 0000:01:00.0:   GRBM_STATUS               = 0xA04C3028
[   40.634547] radeon 0000:01:00.0:   GRBM_STATUS_SE0           = 0x08000006
[   40.634549] radeon 0000:01:00.0:   GRBM_STATUS_SE1           = 0x00000006
[   40.634551] radeon 0000:01:00.0:   SRBM_STATUS               = 0x200000C0
[   40.634608] radeon 0000:01:00.0:   SRBM_STATUS2              = 0x00000000
[   40.634609] radeon 0000:01:00.0:   R_008674_CP_STALLED_STAT1 = 0x00000000
[   40.634611] radeon 0000:01:00.0:   R_008678_CP_STALLED_STAT2 = 0x00018000
[   40.634612] radeon 0000:01:00.0:   R_00867C_CP_BUSY_STAT     = 0x00000000
[   40.634614] radeon 0000:01:00.0:   R_008680_CP_STAT          = 0x80030243
[   40.634615] radeon 0000:01:00.0:   R_00D034_DMA_STATUS_REG   = 0x44C83D57
[   40.634617] radeon 0000:01:00.0:   R_00D834_DMA_STATUS_REG   = 0x44C83D57
[   40.634619] radeon 0000:01:00.0:   VM_CONTEXT1_PROTECTION_FAULT_ADDR   0x00000000
[   40.634620] radeon 0000:01:00.0:   VM_CONTEXT1_PROTECTION_FAULT_STATUS 0x00000000
[   41.187364] radeon 0000:01:00.0: GRBM_SOFT_RESET=0x0000DDFF
[   41.187422] radeon 0000:01:00.0: SRBM_SOFT_RESET=0x00000100
[   41.188577] radeon 0000:01:00.0:   GRBM_STATUS               = 0x00003028
[   41.188583] radeon 0000:01:00.0:   GRBM_STATUS_SE0           = 0x00000006
[   41.188588] radeon 0000:01:00.0:   GRBM_STATUS_SE1           = 0x00000006
[   41.188593] radeon 0000:01:00.0:   SRBM_STATUS               = 0x200000C0
[   41.188652] radeon 0000:01:00.0:   SRBM_STATUS2              = 0x00000000
[   41.188657] radeon 0000:01:00.0:   R_008674_CP_STALLED_STAT1 = 0x00000000
[   41.188661] radeon 0000:01:00.0:   R_008678_CP_STALLED_STAT2 = 0x00000000
[   41.188666] radeon 0000:01:00.0:   R_00867C_CP_BUSY_STAT     = 0x00000000
[   41.188670] radeon 0000:01:00.0:   R_008680_CP_STAT          = 0x00000000
[   41.188675] radeon 0000:01:00.0:   R_00D034_DMA_STATUS_REG   = 0x44C83D57
[   41.188679] radeon 0000:01:00.0:   R_00D834_DMA_STATUS_REG   = 0x44C83D57
[   41.188812] radeon 0000:01:00.0: GPU reset succeeded, trying to resume
[   41.201858] [drm] PCIE gen 3 link speeds already enabled
[   41.208907] [drm] PCIE GART of 2048M enabled (table at 0x0000000000165000).
[   41.209009] radeon 0000:01:00.0: WB enabled
[   41.209011] radeon 0000:01:00.0: fence driver on ring 0 use gpu addr 0x0000000040000c00
[   41.209012] radeon 0000:01:00.0: fence driver on ring 1 use gpu addr 0x0000000040000c04
[   41.209013] radeon 0000:01:00.0: fence driver on ring 2 use gpu addr 0x0000000040000c08
[   41.209014] radeon 0000:01:00.0: fence driver on ring 3 use gpu addr 0x0000000040000c0c
[   41.209015] radeon 0000:01:00.0: fence driver on ring 4 use gpu addr 0x0000000040000c10
[   41.209279] radeon 0000:01:00.0: fence driver on ring 5 use gpu addr 0x0000000000075a18
[   41.209708] debugfs: File 'radeon_ring_gfx' in directory '0' already present!
[   41.209711] debugfs: File 'radeon_ring_cp1' in directory '0' already present!
[   41.209712] debugfs: File 'radeon_ring_cp2' in directory '0' already present!
[   41.209713] debugfs: File 'radeon_ring_dma1' in directory '0' already present!
[   41.209715] debugfs: File 'radeon_ring_dma2' in directory '0' already present!
[   41.555764] [drm:r600_ring_test [radeon]] *ERROR* radeon: ring 0 test failed (scratch(0x850C)=0xCAFEDEAD)
[   41.555800] [drm:si_resume [radeon]] *ERROR* si startup failed on resume
[   51.862544] radeon 0000:01:00.0: ring 0 stalled for more than 10388msec
[   51.862562] radeon 0000:01:00.0: GPU lockup (current fence id 0x0000000000000001 last fence id 0x0000000000000002 on ring 0)
[   52.376593] radeon 0000:01:00.0: ring 0 stalled for more than 10900msec
[   52.376611] radeon 0000:01:00.0: GPU lockup (current fence id 0x0000000000000001 last fence id 0x0000000000000002 on ring 0)
[   52.890434] radeon 0000:01:00.0: ring 0 stalled for more than 11412msec
[   52.890452] radeon 0000:01:00.0: GPU lockup (current fence id 0x0000000000000001 last fence id 0x0000000000000002 on ring 0)
```

Comment: Did you ever solve your problem?